# linux sftp :file transfer error

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sftp

I have a small problem regarding "sftp".

I have a script, which simply transfers a file  to a remote sftp server. But when this script runs it fails at sftp and my script fails.
So, i have to manually transfer the file,using command which is same as the command that i have used in the script, and it works fine.

So my problem is that the sftp command runs smoothly when i run it manually, but creates problem when the same command is run through the script.

this is the code that I'm using

```
sftp -v -b sftp_input.txt UserId@aa.bb.cc.dd 
if (($? > 0 ));
then
   echo "sftp  error. Exiting.."
   exit
fi
```

where  sftp_input.txt contains the cmd to put the file to remote server.

Please advice.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script can't work because it's malformed. You forgot to separate the `if` statement and also forgot the closing `fi`. Here's the correct form for your script:

```
sftp -v -b sftp_input.txt UserId@aa.bb.cc.ddd
if (($? > 0 )); then
    echo "sftp error. Exiting.."
    exit
fi
```

If you want it all in one line, then:

```
sftp -v -b sftp_input.txt UserId@aa.bb.cc.ddd; if (($? > 0 )); then echo "sftp error. Exiting.."; exit; fi
```

But as you can see it's a bad idea. Better to write readable and well indented code.